# Adjucating a 5e sunder attempt

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

*Rotgarth the Orc Barbarian* wants to break *Anne the Purple Dragoon*'s halberd (he's probably tired of all those polearm master's AoO).

Looking up the [rules for objects](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Objects#content), Rot can see that the halberd's shaft is:

- Made of wood (AC 15)
- Medium sized (some 8' long maybe?)
- Probably Resilient (18 HP) <sub>those cormyrian halberds **are** made to last. [That is why they sell so fast](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0136.html)...</sub>

Rot is really excited. The halberd shaft probably won't resist a couple blows from his greataxe, specially in his raging hands. Grummsh be glorified, but...

How does one goes about attacking an object in possession of an enemy?

Answer (score 2):

### There are no rules for sundering in 5e, but try disarming.

While there are no explicit rules for sundering, it seems like the disarming rules on DMG 271 would be appropriate for your particular example:

> A creature can use a weapon attack to knock a weapon or another item from a target's grasp. The attacker makes an attack roll contested by the target's Strength (Athletics) check or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check.

Once the item is separated from its user, then you can adjudicate its destruction according to the rules for objects that you cite, which seem to be written for unattended objects.